# Python random unique value for multiple variables

Tags: python, random

The issue I'm having is that I need to set letters a-z a random unique value from 1 to 26. The same number equalling multiple letters is what I want to avoid. Current methods I have is over 70 lines and is just while loops of each letter to not equal the value given previously for a different letter. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried the random() method? https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html

Answer (score 2):

Use `random.sample()`, which can take any number of unique elements from a given interval. If you take the entire iterable using it, then you get elements in an effectively random order. For example, the following snippet maps the letters in the alphabet to random numbers `1` through `26`, without repeating any.

```
import random

alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
numbers = range(1, len(alphabet) + 1)
correspondence = list(zip(alphabet, random.sample(numbers, len(alphabet))))
print(correspondence)
# [('a', 21), ('b', 19), ('c', 2),  ('d', 14), ('e', 12), ('f', 3), 
#  ('g', 8),  ('h', 11), ('i', 10), ('j', 4),  ('k', 5),  ('l', 22), 
#  ('m', 18), ('n', 20), ('o', 16), ('p', 23), ('q', 1),  ('r', 25), 
#  ('s', 9),  ('t', 15), ('u', 26), ('v', 7),  ('w', 17), ('x', 24), 
#  ('y', 6),  ('z', 13)]
```

Comment: How can I change so that every letter in the alphabet is interpreted as a variable to equal the number. Also I don't really understand how 'zip' function works can you explain that because I'm a bit of a noob. Thanks.

Comment: `zip()` takes several iterables, and 'zips' them together into one iterable with corresponding elements (try opening a python console and doing `help(zip)`. To add them all as actual variable names and values in the local namespace, you could do `locals().update(correspondence)`. To add them throughout the entire program, `globals().update(correspondence)` instead (similarly, try opening a python console and doing `help(locals)` and `help(globals)` to understand what happens here). You might just want to make `correspondence` a `dict`, though - just do `dict(correspondence)`.

Comment: Not to be rude but I didn't really understand anything you said but I found a solution by myself already so it's fine. thanks for trying to explain though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `random.shuffle()` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle)) and `chr()` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr)) to get your desired outputs.

[ASCII](https://roubaixinteractive.com/PlayGround/Binary_Conversion/The_Characters.asp) lower alphabet characters start from 97.

```py
import random

numbers = list(range(1,27))

random.shuffle(numbers)

for num in numbers:
  print(f'Letter={chr(96+num)}, Random Number={num}')
```

Outputs:

```
Letter=v, Random Number=22
Letter=t, Random Number=20
Letter=u, Random Number=21
Letter=w, Random Number=23
Letter=f, Random Number=6
Letter=b, Random Number=2
Letter=d, Random Number=4
Letter=h, Random Number=8
Letter=z, Random Number=26
.
.
.
.
```

---

You can also use `random.sample()`. More info [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample).

One liner:

```py
result = [(chr(96+num), num) for num in random.sample(list(range(1,27)), 26)]
```

Outputs:

```
[('p', 16), ('x', 24), ('d', 4), ('f', 6), ('w', 23), ('z', 26), ('m', 13), ('n', 14), ('b', 2), ('a', 1), ('s', 19), ('q', 17), ('t', 20), ('u', 21), ('h', 8), ('l', 12), ('e', 5), ('k', 11), ('g', 7), ('c', 3), ('v', 22), ('r', 18), ('j', 10), ('i', 9), ('o', 15), ('y', 25)]
```